# Save a partial video file locally using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg

I have a serverless web application that is deployed on `AWS` and I have to take a screenshot from an uploaded video to `S3`. I am using `ffmpeg` to extract the screenshot but the only drawback is that I have to download the video file first in order to let `ffmpeg` work with it.
Knowing the fact I am using `AWS Lambda` and I don't have limits for video length users might upload large files which makes `AWS Lambda` to hit the storage limit.
To overcome this I thought of downloading a small chunk of the video and use it with `ffmpeg` to extract the thumbnail so using the `S3.getOjbect` method with range params I was able to download a chunk of the file but `ffmpeg` couldn't understand it.
Here is my code:

```
s3.getObject({
  Bucket: bucketName,
  Key: key,
  Range: 'bytes=0-1048576'
}, (err, data) => {
  fs.writeFile(fileName, data.Body, error => {
    if (error)
      console.log(error)
    else
      console.log('File saved');
  })
})
```

And the code to extract the thumbnail:

```
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
new ffmpeg(fileName).screenshots({
  timestamps: [0],
  filename: 'thumb.png',
  folder: '.'
})
```

And I am getting this error from `ffmpeg`

```
Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: ./test.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
```

I know there is a problem in saving the file like this but I couldn't find any solution that solves my problem. If anybody has one that would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
It turns out that `ffmpeg` does this for me, I just gave it the `url` and it downloaded what it needs to render the screenshot without the need to download the file locally and the code looks like this:

```
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
new ffmpeg(url).screenshots({
  timestamps: [0],
  filename: 'thumb.png',
  folder: '.'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that you would need to understand the format of mp4 and make sure you are fetching enough data to line up along a frame boundary, and then alter any headers so that ffmpeg can understand the partial data and doesn't think it just has a corrupted file.

While you're inside the AWS ecosystem you could try using Elastic Transcode to transcode the video and ask it to generate a thumbnail?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/preset-settings.html#preset-settings-thumbnails

Comment: I don't want to use Elastic Transcoder simply because I don't want to transcode the video. I only want a screenshot for the first frame of the video.